# comparing a name entered by first letter

Tags: java, string-comparison

This is my first post on here and I'm very new to Java, so be gentle.

I'm on an assignment using compareTo() and basically the users will enter their name. If that name comes before, after or in between some names I already have set in String, then it will display a message accordingly.

I'm basically wondering what's the easiest way to do this? Convert the names to `int`s so I can more easily do nameA > nameB ... and so on

```
int result;
String name;    
String nameB = "Baggins";
String nameD = "Dresden";
String nameH = "Howl";
String nameP = "Potter";
String nameV = "Vimes";

System.out.println("What's your last name?");
name = inputReader.next();

result = name.compareTo (nameB);

if (result < 0){
    System.out.println("Great! You are on team Red Dragons.");
}
```

This should work for this line, but now I need to see if what they enter is in between nameB and nameD and I can't use `>` and `<` with strings.

Comment: Open the sources of the String (or CharSequence maybe) class...

Comment: You can write your own Comparator class to compare the first letter of two strings

Comment: One other hackish approach would be to have condition like: `if (name.compareTo (nameB) < 0 && name.compareTo (nameD) > 0)`. However the solution suggested by @cricket_007 is more better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let try it

```
if(name.compareTo(nameB) >= 0 && name.compareTo(nameD) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeSet (sorted set with useful methods):

```
TreeSet names = new TreeSet<String>((a,b) -> a.compareTo(b));
//or other comparator, eg: (a,b)-> a.substring(0,2).compareTo(b.substring(0,2));
names.add("Baggins");
names.add("Dresden");
....
names.higher(input); // name higher than input
names.lower(input);
```